# Passing app data to a specific text field in a webpage

Tags: ios, uiwebview, textfield, wkwebview

I am writing an iOS and I don't mind whether to use WKWebView or UIWebView. What I want to accomplish is to pass some data (e.g. a search text) from the app **to a specific text field of the webpage** embedded in the app. The main **use case** is to **pre-populate webpage fields** (e.g. with data from a barcode).

E.g. passing from, lets call it MyStackOverflowLibrary app some text into the search field box on the top right page of the StackOverflow website.

Comment: Do you have control over the implementation of the web page?

Comment: @tobiasbayer Yes, I can get the people that developed it to change it but needs a long approval process.. so need to prototype it first. However would be good to understand if it is possible to do it also without changing the webpage source.

Comment: Then @aeskreis' answer should work for you. Just implement some JavaScript that changes the field content and call it from Objective-C with the method mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 
`[UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:]`.
You must of course implement a `UIWebViewDelegate` so you know when the page is fully loaded, or your javascript will not run.  You should be able to populate the field in this manner.

Comment: is there a similar function for WKWebView?

Comment: Yes, [WKWebView evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:], see the documentation for details: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/